# Azure Active Directory - we couldn't sign you in. please try again

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm getting the error We couldn't sign you in. Please try again. when I try to login to my custom web app that uses Azure AD.

when I restart the azure app service, it is working fine for some time. May be I am missing some configuration

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your app is "going to sleep" after a period of inactivity?
Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-connection-strings) at the description of the "Always On" option:

> Always On: Keeps the app loaded even when there's no traffic. It's required for continuous WebJobs or for WebJobs that are triggered using a CRON expression.

In the portal, the option is descripbed as:

> Prevents your app from being idled out due to inactivity.

Possibly, the idling out of your app causes the next login attempt to fail due to a timeout while it's warming up?
Restarting the app service means its hot and ready to go.

Comment: Hi Paul, I have verified the settings. Always On is already enabled.